# How to add bitcoin wallet to Mt. Gox?

Tags: transactions

I am fairly new to this and I am worried I just wasted 300. It just says out of sync. How do I add my bitcoin wallet to Mt. Gox?

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* keep your funds on Mt. Gox, it is not advisable to do so, for the reasons [listed here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/pros-and-cons-of-using-mt-gox-as-an-e-wallet). So you would better find an e-wallet you like (I suggest blockchain.info), and send your funds there.

Always keep a backup, and never forget your passphrase!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to hear you accidentally 300 - we've all been there at one point or another. To answer your questions:

[I sent bitcoins to a bitcoin client that hadn't fully synced - are my bitcoins lost?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/help-i-sent-coins-to-my-bitcoin-wallet-before-it-was-properly-synced)

> How do I add my bitcoin wallet to Mt. Gox?

[Click "Add Funds", choose Bitcoins](https://support.mtgox.com/entries/20290301-Step-2-Adding-Funds)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding funds by using bitcoins, and it did not give me an option to add my bitcoin wallet.

Comment: -1 while this answers the exact question asked, I think it would have been much better to explain to the OP what was he doing wrong and dissuade him (sorry)