# New to BitCoin - Purchased Coins but they haven't shown up in my wallet yet - Wallet still syncing

Tags: wallet

I purchased some BitCoins last night.  I downloaded the BitCoin client around a year ago but and only had it open once or twice for just a short time.

Because of that, my wallet is still synchronizing and looks like it will continue doing so for quite some time.  lol

Needless to say, my wallet is still at zero...  Did I screw myself over by transferring coins before my wallet ever initially synced?

It was a small, small amount thankfully, just to try it out (as I said, I'm a newbie).  :)

Any help is appreciated it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help! I sent coins to my bitcoin wallet before it was properly synced!](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/help-i-sent-coins-to-my-bitcoin-wallet-before-it-was-properly-synced)

Comment: Check blockexplorer / blockchain.info with address, or public key..

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for your wallet to synchronize.  It won't show up in your wallet until you have the block that contains the transaction, which would be a very recent block.