# Wallet Out of Sync and Bitcoin transfer

Tags: wallet, synchronization

I bought bitcoins and sent them to the wallet, however the wallet is not synchronized and as a result I cannot see my bitcoins. Will I be able to see them as soon as the synch process finishes or have I lost them? And if I did, is there any way I can recover them?

Comment: what is the risk of losing those bitcoins?

Comment: The risk is zero. You are already the owner, just your software hasn't caught up to that information yet. – This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. Please refer to [about] for a quick overview on how Bitcoin.SE functions.

Answer (score 1):

In case of an offline wallet such as Bitcoin-Qt, you will need to be synchronised/update before you see your wallet balance correctly. The Bitcoin client will download the whole blockchain if it is the first time. Once it has been downloaded and you synchronize daily, it will be much faster to do so.

There is an existing answer on [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/help-i-sent-coins-to-my-bitcoin-wallet-before-it-was-properly-synced).