# How can I regain coins on a device with insufficient memory to fully synchronize?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have started syncing the blocks and didn't know how much room was need, I am about 40 gb through and my device is full. I already have money on the account, but it isn't synced far enough to send the bitcoins out.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/help-i-sent-coins-to-my-bitcoin-wallet-before-it-was-properly-synced

Answer (score 1):

You can always save the private key and import it to another wallet, or in a web wallet for more convenience.

Comment: Be very careful with webwallets or anything else you give your private key to. They can just take your money and run.